# JBoss not redirecting to Keycloak

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I have JBoss EAP 7

So I have done:

`unzip keycloak-eap7-adapter-dist-3.2.1.Final.zip`

and

`./bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=adapter-install-offline.cli`

and added the `<security-constraint>` element to web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admins</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        ...

<security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
...
```

and in my `standalone.xml`, I have:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
            <secure-deployment name="snack.war">
                <realm>Netzportal</realm>
                <resource>netzportal</resource>
                <public-client>true</public-client>
                <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8180/auth</auth-server-url>
                <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
            </secure-deployment>
        </subsystem>
```

And in the keycloak admin console I have registered the web application as client. The client opens at `http://localhost:10080/czo/login.xhtml`. So I have entered `http://localhost:10080/czo/*` as `Valid Redirect URIs`.

But when the application is running and I open `http://localhost:10080/czo/login.xhtml`, I do not get redirected to keycloak (which is also running)

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be missing following entry ( since it does not appear in your listed `web.xml` configuration) which actually tell which kind of authentication to use for login

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
   <realm-name>Netzportal</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

For more details on configuration check the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#jboss-eap-wildfly-adapter).

Comment: Doesn't this paragraph in the linked docs indicate he shouldn't have to do that though? (Apologies if that were true 2 years ago)
You do not have to modify your WAR to secure it with Keycloak. Instead you can externally secure it via the Keycloak Adapter Subsystem. While you don’t have to specify KEYCLOAK as an auth-method, you still have to define the security-constraints in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after a lot of suffering, I found that the web.xml file in the wrong folder